# Passing multiple input fields between React Form state-less component and state-full Root component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, state

I'm a beginner with React and I'm attempting to make an address book application (front-end only, for now). I have my root component called App in the App.js file and I'm trying to move the form element from the root component into its own component (state-less I guess) in the AddContact.js file. I was able to find a way (searching SO) to pass the form input fields when the form is part of the root component to the form submit handler function. But I'm not able to do the same when the form element is part of a different component. Below are the App.js and AddContact.js files. How should I go about doing so? Preferably in the simplest way, while adhering to react/es6 best practices.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
//import AddContact from './AddContact/AddContact';
//import './AddContact/AddContact.css';
import ContactList from './ContactList/ContactList.js';
import Cockpit from './Cockpit/Cockpit.js';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    contacts:[]
  };

  addContactHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log(event.target[0].value);
    //console.log(event.target.name.value);
    const name = this.input1.value;
    const phone = this.input2.value;
    const email = this.input3.value;
    let contacts = [...this.state.contacts];
    if (name.length>0 && phone.length>0 && email.length>0){

      let contact = {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email
      };
      contacts.push(contact);
      console.log("contacts: ", contacts);
      this.setState({
        contacts:contacts
      });
    }
    this.input1.value = '';
    this.input2.value = ''; 
    this.input3.value = '';

  };

  render() {
    let contactList = null;
    let contacts = [...this.state.contacts];
    if (contacts.length > 0) {
        contactList = (
          <ContactList
          contacts = {contacts}
          />
        );
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Cockpit/>
        <p>Add New Contact:</p>
        <form className="AddContact" onSubmit={(event)=>this.addContactHandler(event)}>
            <label>Name: 
                <input type="text" name="name" ref={(name) => {this.input1 = name}}/>
            </label>
            <label>Phone: 
                <input type="text" name="phone" ref={(phone) => {this.input2 = phone}}/>
            </label>
            <label>Email: 
                <input type="text" name="email" ref={(email) => {this.input3 = email}}/>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        {/* <AddContact submit={(event)=>this.addContactHandler(event)}/> */}
        {contactList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

AddContact.js

```
// Use at a later stage
import React from 'react';
import './AddContact.css';

const AddContact = (props) => {
    return (
        <div >
            <p>Add New Contact:</p>
            <form className="AddContact" onSubmit={props.submit}>
                <label>Name: 
                    <input type="text" ref={(name) => {this.input = name}}/>
                </label>
                <label>Phone: 
                    <input type="text" ref={(phone) => {this.input2 = phone}}/>
                </label>
                <label>Email: 
                    <input type="text" ref={(email) => {this.input3 = email}}/>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddContact;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the form element into its own dedicated component is a great approach. But don't try to handle the child component's form submit event from the parent component. The child component owns the form, it should handle its mutations and submission too. With that in mind, this is how I'd structure the components:

1. Your `App` renders the `AddContact` component.
2. For your `AddContact` component, don't pass an `onSubmit` handler to it. Instead, pass an `onAdd` handler that expects a `contact` object as its argument.
3. Make your `AddContact` component stateful! Is there any particular reason you would want it to be stateless? Make it stateful, let it handle form updates as part of its state (use [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)). And finally, on the form `onSubmit` event, package up a `contact` object and call the `props.onAdd` handler with it.

This will be a cleaner, more rationally separated architecture for your components. The parent component shouldn't have to worry about a child component's form submit behavior, but should rather expect a nicely packaged up `contact` object.

Check this out: https://mn627xy99.codesandbox.io/

```
class AddContact extends React.Component {

    state = {
        name: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
    }

    submit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onAdd(this.state);

        // Clear the form
        this.setState({name: "", phone: "", email: ""});
    }

    change = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({[e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <p>Add New Contact:</p>
                <form className="AddContact" onSubmit={this.submit}>
                    <label>Name: 
                        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.name} />
                    </label>
                    <label>Phone: 
                        <input type="text" name="phone" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.phone} />
                    </label>
                    <label>Email: 
                        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.email} />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Arash. I have it working (for the most part) with the following `return` statement in my App.js file: `return (
      <div className="App">
        <Cockpit/>
        <AddContact onAdd={(newContact)=>this.addContactHandler(newContact)}/> 
        {contactList}
      </div>
    );`

Comment: the only issue I'm having is, that I'm unable to clear the form after submitting it. I've tried setting the value of the event.target(or currentTarget).name to an empty string with no success. I've tried this in the form submit handler function `e.currentTarget.phone.value="";`

Comment: Cool! Please read that **Controlled Components** section that I linked in my answer carefully. That's an important concept in React. The key is you shouldn't directly change the value of the input element. Instead, you just set the **state** of your component to whatever you like it to be, and the elements and components will be automatically updated to display the value that you set in your state. I'll update my answer so you can see how it works.

Comment: I got it, thanks! `submit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            name: "",
            phone: "",
            email: "",
        });
        this.props.onAdd(this.state);
    }`

Comment: You got it! React will take a little getting used to, and you'll have to deliberately forget some of the old jQuery ways of doing things, but once you get comfortable with it, you'll like it a lot :) Good luck on your journey.

Comment: Quick comment on your comment: before you clear the state, make sure to capture its current values. In other words, clear the state **after** you call the `onAdd` handler. `setState` changes the state asynchronously, which means if you clear the state before calling the handler, then you **might** end up passing an empty state into your handler. So, to be safe, either call the handler first, or at least **copy** the state into another object (e.g. `const newContact = {...this.state}`) before you clear your state.